Preview in Jetpack Compose - should preview have their own file
I am new to Compose and especially to Preview. Is there any common pattern to how to manage Compose Preview functions ? Like should they have separate file for previews or be within the component they preview ? And how not to include them in Release build ?
Thanks!

you can preview in compose component you create. Preview will not be shown when you run the app on emulator or phone so this won't affect release builds

What do you mean by “Preview will not be shown when you run the app”? The Preview function is inside the component file, so logically, it seems that it would be compiled into the release APK. For example, an APK with 100 preview functions should be larger than an APK with 0 preview functions, right?

It's a good idea to place the preview in the same file as the original composable, because:

preview & composable are tightly coupled
it's very handy to have a preview right next to the code you're developing
the "most official" sample app does it that way


It's a good idea to place the preview at the bottom of the file, so it's "out of the way": Usually no-one cares about the preview implementation, but about the component itself


And how not to include them in Release build?

Android includes a tool called Proguard/R8 which can remove all unnecessary code from your app, including previews.
While this offers massive benefits (my apk size was reduced by roughly 50%) it's often not as easy as just enabling it. See the documentation for more information

I recognize it is the currently recommended way of doing it, but it also seems like a tooling issue? To me it sounds like you should be able to write Previews into your test source set so its automatically excluded and the IDE should just pick it up from there and show it next to your file. Especially in Compose Multiplatform this would be very useful since there are many source sets which have various problems with Preview at the moment. You should be able to see Previews for all platforms all at once.
